# React-leaflet get ctrlKey press event

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-leaflet

I try to handle ctrlKey + click vs click event.

**eventHandler**

```
   seatClickHandler = (event, seat) => {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(seat);
    };
```

**component on which is clicked.**

```
<Circle onClick={ (event) => this.seatClickHandler(event, seat) }
        key={seat['id']}
        center={[x, y]}
        radius={7} />
```

I tried to check for `event.ctrlKey` but it is undefined.

How can I find out if ctrl or shift key is holding on click happens?

> Problem is that I can not use reactJs events from react-leaflet event.
>   In example if I run `event.stopPropagation();` I get fatal error.

Comment: I had checked solution from this answer but still no solution.
I can not use react events from a leaflet event.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Leaflet has its [own events](https://leafletjs.com/reference-1.3.0.html#mouseevent). If you want to access the original click event you need to do it through the `originalEvent` property on the leaflet event:

```
if (event.originalEvent.ctrlKey) {
    // handle ctrl + click ...
}
```

Every property you expect a `DOMEvent` to have will be on this object instead of the leaflet event object. This does also include `stopPropagation()`.